# Java Spring MVC mapping issue

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I know that maybe other ppl already asked this question and I checked all of the relevant questions here at stackoverflow but I can't fix my problem and I was hoping someone from you can help me.  I'm learning Spring MVC right now and I deal with simple pages for now. For some reason my code can't load even though I to everything correct(Or at least I think that I do). 
When I try to access the localhost:8080/PROJECTNAME/welcome
I get **Description** The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

The Error from Java is: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/ProjetName/welcome] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-dispatcher'.

I Use Apache Tomcat 8.5, which is integrated in the Eclipse IDE
And also JDK 8

Here is my Code.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id = "WebApp_ID" version = "2.4"
xmlns = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">



 <display-name>MySpringMVCWebApp</display-name>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
  </servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

 </web-app>
```

spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="org.mypackagename.com.*"> 
</context:component-scan>
 <bean id="viewResolver" 
        class = 
  "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name = "prefix" value ="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
  <property name = "suffix" value =".jsp"/>
  </bean>
```

HelloController.java

```
package org.mypackagename.com;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public ModelAndView helloWorld() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("HelloPage");
    mav.addObject("msg", "Helloooooooooooo");
    return mav;

  }


 }
```

HelloPage.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Spring MVC</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>${msg}</h2>

 </body>
 </html>
```

HelloController.java was changed in order to work below is the updated code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController {
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)public String printHello(ModelMap 
model) {
  model.addAttribute("message", "Hello the fcking Spring MVC Framework!");
  return "hello";
 }
```

Comment: <mvc:annotation-driven />
add this to spring config

Comment: @Arun I've already tried. It doesn't help. Besides `xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"` which is also added does the same work and when I try with `<mvc:annotation-driven />` I get the error that this thing is not bound

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/welcome", method = GET) add this to your controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your servlet-mapping as below

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

specifying url-pattern as **/ only matches until  `host/servlet`**  or `'localhost:8080/PROJECTNAME/'`

**Update:**

Configure **default** or **home page** in your spring **controller** as below.

Instead of

```
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
```

do

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = GET)
```

Comment: There is no error withing the Eclipse IDE i.e. in the console of the server but rather when I try to load up the page. The error is:

*Type* Status Report

**Message** /SpringMVCProject/welcome
**Description** The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/8.5.33

Comment: Check out my code for the HelloController.java
but then I just put in the browser tab `http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCProject/welcome`

Comment: I saw your updated answer. However just replacing ``@RequestMapping("/welcome")`` by ``@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = GET)`` doesn't not help, because it doesn't know what ``GET`` is and it wants me to create new constant as it cannot be resolved to variable which doesn't help. Maybe I should change the whole method which comes after it ? I mean this part ``public ModelAndView helloWorld() {``

Comment: Your answer wasn't quite right, but it helped me find the correct one. So I think I'm gonna give you the right answer point as it was the thing that gave me the idea to change my method.

Answer (score 0):

`<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` You didn't specify any application context. So either add `PROJECTNAME` to your mapping or access it through localhost:8080/welcome

Comment: I tried to add
``<servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/SpringMVCProject</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>``  and also  ``/SpringMVCProject/welcome`` but still an error HTTP 404 Not Found

Comment: I didn't add it. When I was writing the code and you close the `>` Eclipse adds it automatically. Anyway, I just removed it and added only `<context:component-scan base-package="org.mypackagename.com.*"/>` but still the same problem

Comment: Sorry, it's my mistake)